# Finding the dictionary with the most number of keys from a list of dicts

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Given a list of dicts `items`, I want to identify **the dict that has the largest number of keys**. More accurately: I want to get its `index()` in the list (or other suitable approach), so that I can subsequently access the values of some of its keys.

To get the size of the item which the largest number of keys (of which there will be more than one), I do:

```
max([len(item.keys()) for item in items])
```

How do I modify this (with `index()` or other) to identify that item? *Any* of them of this max size will suffice). Each dict has a key `name` that will always be unique in the list.

Comment: If you have numpy, you can use `np.argmax`.

Comment: Don't use `len(item.keys())` if this is just an ordinary dictionary - `len(item)` is the way to do it.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Fair point, well made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you don't actually need the index of the largest dictionary and instead just need the dictionary itself:

```
largest_dictionary = max(items, key=len)
```

where `items` is your `list` of `dict`s.

Comment: `Assuming you don't actually need the index of the largest dictionary` - yep, getting the index was my just my intitial thinking about a cumbersome, multi-step way way of achieving tis. Neat solution, thanks. Wasn't aware that `max()` had the `key` argument.

Comment: @Pyderman If the index is not required, this is certainly the answer for you. If it helps, do consider marking this answer accepted.

Answer (score 4):

You're looking for the argmax. In python, that would be done with `max` + `enumerate`.

```
i, d = max(enumerate(items), key=lambda x: len(x[1]))
```

Where `d` is the `dict` with the highest number of keys, and `i` is its index.